# Why does my cloth simulation fail after shrinking my cloths down to real world scale (7x smaller)

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, scale

The framerate reduces to zero exponentially. All the meshes are to scale including the clothes. The cloth-collision and self-collision distance properties where reduced by 7, but nothing changed lag-wise. If I turn off both self-collision on the cloth and collision on the mesh, the lag reduces. With self-collision off, and collision on, the clothes appears twice as large as the mesh. My mesh has around 20,000 vertices.

Comment: After *'shrinking'* the cloth, do you apply Scale?

Comment: Of course I did.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my mesh is incorrectly parented to my armature and is using global coordinates instead of actual coordinates. Clearing and reapplying parent fixes the issue, it messes up the weight painting though.